# scroll to the tag by its value/content after clicking on a link

Tags: html, angular, angular8

I have a link whose value is coming from an api and Details of that link are displayed later in the page.
I want to scroll down to specific details. Details are also coming from an api so I can not write an id to each and every detail available.

e.g. HTML

```
<div class="row ml-0 mr-0 pb-2" *ngFor="let advance of advanceDetails">
                <div class="col-4 dl-value"><a (click)="scroll()">{{advance.AdvNumber}}</a></div>
</div>
```

This is where I want to scroll:

```
<div class="row ml-0 mr-0" *ngFor="let advance of advanceDetails">
                <div class="col-5">
                <label class="dl-label">Advance Number</label>
                <p class="dl-value">{{advance.AdvNumber}}</p>
              </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <label class="dl-label">Other Details</label>
                <p class="dl-value">{{advance.details}}</p>
            </div>
</div>
```

I want to scroll down by value of advance number. what will be inside scroll() function in ts? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not the cleanest way, but you can set a unique id to each item with ngFor indexes.

Then, get the element by id with the unique ID (and check if the element exist), finally scroll to it with scrollIntoView function.

Component.html

```
<div class="list" *ngFor="let advance of advanceDetails; let i = index">
  <div class="list-item" id="advanced-{{i}}">
    <p>{{advance.details}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Component.ts

```
scroll(id : any) {
  const advancedItemSelected = document.getElementById('advanced-' + id); 
  if (advancedItemSelected) {
    advancedItemSelected.scrollIntoView(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: what should I pass to scroll function in html?

Comment: <div class="row ml-0 mr-0 pb-2" *ngFor="let advance of advanceDetails; let i = index" >
 <div class="col-4 dl-value">
  <a (click)="scroll(i)">{{advance.AdvNumber}}</a>
 </div>
</div>